# First page load slow PHPBB 3.0.11

Tags: php, sql, performance, phpbb

I have a site that is running PHPBB 3.0.11 (latest version) but on first page visit with empty cache it takes 4-5 seconds to load. After that it loads in seconds! Any ideas?

Forum: http://takeahike.org.uk/forum

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any modifications to your board ? a link to your forum might help..

Comment: There are no mod installed, I've updated the question with a link to the forum, thanks

Comment: Does it happen -with the same code- just in that server, or in localhost or other hosts as well?
First time I loaded the forum,it took around three seconds but then if I load the index or any other page,it loads just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, I figured out the problem. It turned out it was because I had a very large list of banned ip's, I guess phpbb loads these up on initial page load and stores them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have some info on how to make phpbb way faster, my forums load twice as fast as before so I post this here and hope my comment is useful to some of you readers.. it's easier to solve problems if your forum is loading faster, it will be harder to get the well known white screens from Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded and easier to debug your forum.. most of the time these errors are from **modifications** make sure all mods and phpBB forum script are up to date..

first of all, If you have a lot of items in your ban list or a high number of members, then your forum will break and provide you with strange errors and white screens, I believe this isn't what you'd like to see ;)

How to solve and where to start:

1. make sure latest stable version of pecl memcache is installed on your server and enabled in your php.ini use corect path to memcache.so and create forum backup
2. Open config.php and edit it look like below

   ```
   <?php
   // phpBB 3.0.x auto-generated configuration file
   // Do not change anything in this file!
   $dbms = 'mysqli'; // What kind of database do you use?
   $dbhost = 'localhost'; // Your host for most of us localhost will work just fine..
   $dbport = ''; // Only needed if a non-standard port is used...
   $dbname = 'YOUR-DATABASE-NAME';
   $dbuser = 'YOUR-USERNAME';
   $dbpasswd = 'YOUR-PASSWORD';
   $table_prefix = 'phpbb_';
   $acm_type = 'memcache'; // Standard is apc or file, change this to memcache but first you slould make sure it's installed and working corectly!!
   // Add the lines below and: DO NOT CHANGE ORDER!
   @define('PHPBB_ACM_MEMCACHE_HOST', 'localhost'); // Memcache server hostname
   @define('PHPBB_ACM_MEMCACHE_PORT', 11211); // Memcache server poort
   @define('PHPBB_ACM_MEMCACHE_COMPRESS', false); // Compress stored data true or false if used CPU usage will grow but bandwidth will be lower I use it on a 8core server..
   $load_extensions = 'memcache';

   @define('PHPBB_INSTALLED', true);
   // @define('DEBUG', true); // uncommend to debug, it will give you a lot of information -  do not remove if forum is working well
   // @define('DEBUG_EXTRA', true); // uncommend to debug, it will give you a lot of information - do not remove if forum is working well

   ?>
   ```
3. Visit your phpbb forum and enjoy the higher speed

   **NOTE 1:** $load_extensions = 'memcache'; must be **AFTER** the ACM_MEMCACHE settings

   **NOTE 2:** I hope this is a useful message for some of you phpBB users - before edit config.php, make sure you **created a backup** of your files and **make sure memcache is working** and **enabled in php.ini**, use the corect path to memcache.so, find corect memcache path and add **full path** to memcache.so to **php.ini** file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the delay is just in one file, namely the front page, and just the very first time, so no cache issues here:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19056348/StackOverflow/loadtimes.png]

Just a few questions:

- Is there any funky `.htaccess` messing around?
- Have you tried [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org) to profile the execution of the application?
- Does it happen -with the same code- just in that server, or in localhost or other hosts as well?